# Sunspot/Solr indexing terms that have a `-` in them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I've got a string field in one of my models that I want to index for full text search:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
    text :name
  end
end
```

which works great for almost all cases, however, if I have an `Organization` that has a name with a `-` in it, e.g. `Ashlawn-Highlands`, it splits the word into two different terms.

So if I search for `Ashlawn` it finds the Organization or if I search for `Highlands` it finds the Organization, but if I search for `Ashlawn-H` if returns nothing.

How can I get Solr to properly tokenize this string including the `-`?

Joe